# Django: Add Link in View

Tags: python, django, view

In my Django project, I have an Ajax request that returns a JSON response. When there is an error, I would like to present the error text, as well as a link. Something like "There was a problem, please click here". I don't know how to get the link in the JSON, however. Maybe I am thinking about this wrong - any help is appreciated!

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({method: 'POST', url:'/update_count/' + meals, data:{csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}", 'auto-update': auto_update}}).done(function(data) {
            if(data['type']  === 'error'){
                 $('#error-message').html(data['message'])
            }
```

View

```
return JsonResponse({'type': 'error', 'message': 'Only registered users can use this feature. Please click ???????? for more information.'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you're trying to do is best done in the client, and not constructed in the srever.
You should return the url in the json response, and then parse that response in your HTML code.

```
response = {
    'type': 'error',
    'url': <url>
}
```

That way you can wrap the url in an `<a></a>` tag for example in your HTML, or do a million other things to show the user that he has to register.

If you still want to have the html tags in your response, you could use [Django filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe), which allow you to add HTML to your responses